# Javascript Date Of Birth Textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

As a novice, I really don't know much about javascript. Kindly help me in developing a similar work-a-like Date-Of-Birth textbox like here in this link : http://ojas.guj.nic.in/GFJobApply.aspx?sid=wGvtB4mUGuc=&yr=kckKNSEPFLY=&ano=K3JOsteln/k=

Comment: "Right click->View source" might get you started. We're not here to reverse-engineer software or websites.

Comment: @KenWhite: Thanks ken but view source only able to access codes to a few extent.

Comment: We're still not here to reverse engineer things. :-) "I want to write a website that works just like Facebook. How do I do it?" isn't a proper question, either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Solution 1 :**
You can easily use `jquery Datepicker` for your site.

It's looks like below.

[image]

For more information check [**Datepicker**](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

**Solution 2 :** You can use `jQuery input mask plugin`

Usage is as below:

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery.maskedinput-1.2.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            //Input Mask for date of birth or date in general
            $("#txtDOB").mask("99/99/9999");

        });
    </script>
```

for more information check [**HowTo: use jQuery input mask plugin**](http://www.emadmokhtar.com/2011/01/howto-use-jquery-input-mask-plugin-in-asp-net/)

I hope this will help to you.

Comment: +1 for suggesting jQuery.  Hard to go wrong with jQuery.

Comment: @Gus yes your absolutely right.